Failed to resolve vue/compiler-sfc when I try to install Caldera
I try to install Caldera by following the steps explained on this link https://caldera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installing-Caldera.html
I succeed to install every package on the file requirements.txt by typing the command
sudo pip3 install requirements.txt

But when I try to launch Caldera by running the script server.py as follows:
python3 server.py --build

I obtain always the same error which is displayed bellow:

I don't have the right version for the package vite. I have the version v2.9.18 but the require version is >=3.2.25, this is why I obtained this error message.
However I don't succeed to upgrade the version. I have the right version of vue as displayed bellow:

Someone know the right command to upgrade the version of vite? The OS I used is RedHAt.
Thank you in advance
I try to execute the command below to upgrade the package vite but it doesn't work:
npm i vue@3.4.31

